# FROM clause necessary in every SELECT statement

Tags: sql, mysql

is the FROM clause necessary in every SELECT statement?Thanks..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not really - you can use SELECT to initialize a variable.

Examples [from here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

mysql> SELECT 1 + 1;
        -> 2

Comment: I didn't think about variable initialization.

Comment: Didn't Oracle require you to SELECT FROM DUAL?

Comment: @Paul - he's asking about mysql, I believe you are correct about Oracle

Answer (score 7):

Not in MySQL, no. You could do this:

```
SELECT 1 + 1;
```

It will be in some DBMSs though - Oracle for example would require you to do:

```
SELECT 1 + 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: FYI, sql server allows SELECT x as well

Answer (score 1):

No. you can very easily do

```
SELECT 1+1
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: Missed the the MYSQL tab.)

This depends on the database.

In Oracle, IIRC, the from is required. But Oracle has a table DUAL which always returns one row for cases where all the work is being done in the SELECT clause.

On the other hand, SQL Server does not require the FROM, to return the value of a variable just select it:

```
SELECT @myVar
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ocedecio FROM is not required in every statement.

For example I tend to use the following syntax to initialise a table with data

```
insert into status(code, description)
select 'O', 'Open'
union all select 'C', 'Closed'
union all select 'P', 'Parked'
```

etc..

**EDIT** (following comments by gamecat)

The example above demonstrates when SELECT without FROM may have a practical use.
You can of course just call:

```
select 'O', 'Open'
union all select 'C', 'Closed'
union all select 'P', 'Parked'
```

Comment: yep, but what you can use the select part separately, I just gave a practical example where it can be used

Answer (score 0):

Basically in SQL server 2005 FROM keyword is not required for Scalar value functions and system functions but it mandatory for table valued functions.

Scalar valued functions can executable like below syntax

Select functionname(arguments)

Table valued functions can executable like below syntax

Select * from functionname(arguments)

else

Select col1,col2 from functionname(argument1,argument2)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both "**SELECT 1**" and "**SELECT 1 FROM DUAL**" work in latest versions of MySQL.

Interesting enough, "**SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1**" requires a FROM clause: "**SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 1**" is fine. In other platforms, like PostgreSQL, "**SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1**" works fine.

Another oddity: "**SELECT 1 FROM DUAL GROUP BY 1 HAVING 1=1**" works in MySQL 5.7, but fails in MySQL 5.5.

---

Summary of the required/optional FROM clause in different platforms:

- MySQL, MariaDB, Amazon Aurora: optional or use "**FROM dual**".
- Oracle: use "**FROM dual**".
- IBM DB2: use "**FROM sysibm.sysdummy1**".
- Informix: use "**FROM systables WHERE tabid=1**"
- Firebird, InterBase: use "**FROM rdb$database**".
- Microsoft Access: required, but no dummy table. Try using "**FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM first_table_found WHERE 1=0) AS dual**".
- SQL Server, SQL Azure, SQL Server CE, Sybase ASE, SQL Anywhere, Ingres, PostgreSQL, Redshift, SQLite: optional.