# Why COUNT(*) is equal to 1 without FROM clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, sql-server-2012

for a quick check I used a query

```
select COUNT(*) LargeTable
```

and was surprized to see

```
LargeTable
-----------
1
```

seconds later I realized my mistake, made it

```
select COUNT(*) from LargeTable
```

and got expected result

```
(No column name)
-----------
1.000.000+
```

but now I don't understand why `COUNT(*)` returned `1`

it happens if I do `select COUNT(*)` or `declare @x int = COUNT(*); select @x`

another  case

```
declare @EmptyTable table ( Value int )
select COUNT(*) from @EmptyTable
```

returns

```
(No column name)
-----------
0
```

I did't find explanation in SQL standard (http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt, online source is given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949764/1506454)

why `COUNT(*)` returns 1?

Comment: If you leave the from clause then it simply select one single row. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705341/from-clause-necessary-in-every-select-statement)

Comment: Your `LargeTable` is now just the alias of what you're selecting before and `Count(*)` returns 1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, i got it. i wonder why 1 and not 0

Comment: @ASh: this is related and answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357570/why-does-select-count-from-nothing-return-1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SQL Server a `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause works as though it operates against a single row table.

This is not standard SQL. Other RDBMSs provide a utility `DUAL` table with a single row.

So this would be treated effectively the same as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS LargeTable
FROM   DUAL
```

A related Connect Item discussing

```
SELECT 'test'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *)
```

is https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/671475/select-test-where-exists-select

Comment: Note that the thing you add after `COUNT(*)` could be anything (=it's not handled as a table name), it is treated as an alias.

Comment: well, it explains `select COUNT(*)` (which is also equal to 1 in MySql and Oracle, according to SQL fiddle); but that happens here: `declare @x int = COUNT(*)`? [page with Connect topic is not responding] :(

Comment: @ASh - You can see the Google cached version if you search `site:connect.microsoft.com "why does select 'test' where exists (select *) not give any error"` then click on the "cached" link

Answer (score 0):

Because without the **FROM** clause DBMS cannot know [LargeTable] is a table. You tricked it in guessing it's a **COLUMN NAME** alias

You can try it and see

```
select count(*) 'eklmnjdklfgm'
select count(*) eklmnjdklfgm
select count(*) [eklmnjdklfgm]
select count(*)
```

The first 3 examples returns **eklmnjdklfgm** as column name

Answer (score -1):

Count(*) returned 1 because your sentence is not of SQL.

1) In the first sentences, you accounts a table empty, with an only row, since you don't put to which table want to access.

2) In the second case:

```
declare @EmptyTable table ( Value int )
select COUNT(*) from @EmptyTable
```

returns

```
(No column name)
-----------
0
```

You put the variable, but don't determine to which table implement him. For this, do a count and go out 0.